# Atom editor PHP link from Docker container

Tags: php, docker, atom-editor

I'm using Atom editor for my daily job and in my company we're using docker containers with nginx server. I want to integrate PHP with Atom and I have a problem. How to link PHP from a docker container to Atom? I've found some atom installations that was including PHP from docker. But I want to keep my installation of Atom because of settings and config files that I wrote, can someone explain this to me step by step? Thanks.

Links:

https://github.com/rakshazi/docker-atom
https://github.com/twoodby/docker-dev-atom-php

Comment: It is unclear what you actually mean by "integrate PHP with Atom". If you want to edit php files that are used/executed within the docker container, then the answer is: you publish the files not by copying them into the container for deployment, but by sharing the file system folder. You will find that documented.

Comment: I want to have full integraton of PHP enviroment in Atom with php integrator etc. 
article here:
https://php-integrator.github.io/
with this package you need to pass a PHP enviroment path and I can't do  it because it is in docker container.

Comment: Why can't you pass an environment variable into the container setup?

Comment: I don't know where or how to pass this env variable :/

Comment: Easiest is to set environment variables in the Dockerfile, they will get picked up by the process inside a started container obviously. Another way would be to use some orchestration, maybe `supervisord` which allows to interact with the container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to mount your docker daemon container to host directory. you can do this with the following command.

```
$ docker run -v [host directory path]:[container directory path] -it [image name]
```